# Form doesn't align properly on Safari but works well on Chrome

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that works well on Chrome but it `wrap` to on Safari in my Ruby on Rails application.

**Here is the code**

```
.panel.panel-primary
  .panel-heading
    h4.panel-title = t('admin.statistic.filter')

  .panel-body
    = form_for form_target, url: url, html: {method: :get, class: 'form-horizontal', :autocomplete => 'off'} do |f|
      .row
        .col.col-xs-3
          = f.datagrid_label :currency
          = f.datagrid_filter :currency, class: "form-control"
        .col.col-xs-3
          = f.datagrid_label :state
          = f.datagrid_filter :state, class: "form-control"
        .col.col-xs-3
          = f.datagrid_label :type
          = f.datagrid_filter :type, class: "form-control"
        .col.col-xs-6
          = f.datagrid_label :created_at
          .form-inline # This is what I used to make it work well on Chrome, but doesn't work on Safari
            = f.datagrid_filter :created_at, class: "form-control"
        .col.col-xs-2
          = f.submit t('datagrid.form.submit'), class: "btn btn-primary", style: "width: 100%"
        .col.col-xs-2
          = link_to t('datagrid.form.clear'), {:controller => 'admin/statistic/orders', :action => 'show'}, class: 'btn btn-primary', style: "width: 100%"
```

**Chrome Look**

[image: Chrome Look]

**Safari Look**

[image: Safari Look]

`.form-inline` Is what I used to make it work well on Chrome, but doesn't work on Safari

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through `grid columns` in bootstrap, I figured there is not reason my code should not work well on the two browsers. The problem being that Safari calculates differently.

So, I figured out `grid column` already past 12 column in Bootstrap 3 and 24 in Bootstrap 4. Upon adjusting the column I feel should be smaller and extend/increased the number of the part that wrap to new line. it works fine.

In other words, I increase this part `.col-xs-6` in the snippet below to `.col-xs-8`, while I reduced others:

```
.col.col-xs-8
          = f.datagrid_label :created_at
          .form-inline # This is what I used to make it work well on Chrome, but doesn't work on Safari
            = f.datagrid_filter :created_at, class: "form-control"
```

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check https://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html#webkit
shows media queries that might help with this issue